# CodeIgniter email does not work when inside config file

Tags: php, email, codeigniter, configuration

It turns out that CodeIgniter email doesn't work when I'm having the info to SMTP inside an config file called email.php

It do however work perfectly fine when I'm doing this instead:

```
$config = array(*smtp info*);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
```

And having the exact same info to the same server as i tried in the config file.
Could anyone give me a clue why is that?

Ion auth wont sent emails now, so I would prefer to get this config file working. I guess its the problem for that too.

**EDIT:** 
Somehow its working now, not sure why. I tried to change the autoload and made a new email.php config file. I changed the outgoing server to another local one, and its working. But it was still working fine before when i loaded the config directly with the lib load. Not sure why this happened.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but are you sure `email.php` is located at `config/email.php`?

Comment: why would you send emails inside of a config file? seems like a very wrong place for something like that.

Comment: Oh no no, I'm not sending emails inside the config file? Im just trying to get the config for my smtp server inside the email config file. And that is not working at all, however having the exact same info where i load my email library is working fine. As the code example in my question.

Comment: Did you remove the config array when loading the library? Because it should automatically get the configurations from the config file?

Comment: Somehow its working now. See my edit.

Comment: @designer: Feel free to post your solution for the benefit of future visitors or, alternatively, you can simply delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you set you config options in config/email.php and then, in a controller, call:

```
$this->load->library('email');
```

It should work.

But, as I suspect, if you set your config options in config/email.php and then, in your controller, call:

```
$this->load->library('email', $config)
```

It won't work, because you are "overriding" the Email Library configuration with an empty $config array.